# Как определить размеры TabTip.exe (виртуальной клавиатуры) на Windows 10?

Tags: delphi, winapi

Нужно определить размеры (Width, Height) и положение (Left, top) TabTip.exe (виртуальной клавиатуры) на windows 10?

Задача – сместить панель, на которой расположены все компоненты, так что бы поле, которому передали фокус ввода, оказалось над виртуальной клавиатурой.

Работа с Windows 10 ведётся не под админом, но скомпилированный проект запускается от имени администратора!

Следующие решения в Windows 7 работают, в windows 8 выдают неверные значения, в Windows 10 не работают:

```
uses ..., Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Dwmapi
...
procedure TForm1.SizeKeyboard;
var KeyBoardRect: TRect;
    KeyboardWindow : HWND;
begin
  KeyboardWindow := FindWindow('IPTip_Main_Window', nil);
  if (KeyboardWindow <> 0) then
    KeyBoardRect := GetRect1(KeyboardWindow);
  ...
end;
...

function TForm1.GetRect1(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var KeyBoardRect: TRect;
begin
    GetWindowRect(AKeyboardWindow, KeyBoardRect);
    Result := KeyBoardRect;
end;


function TForm1.GetRect2(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var KeyBoardRect: TRect;
begin
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(AKeyboardWindow, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,     @KeyBoardRect, sizeof(KeyBoardRect));

    Result :=  KeyBoardRect;
end;
```

Так как

> The Windows 10 touch keyboard is a UWP application. UWP applications do not have native windows, and cannot be referenced through HWNDs. You can use UI Automation to get the bounding rectangle of the touch keyboard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509973/get-size-of-windows-10-touch-keyboard-window

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671425(v=vs.85).aspx

Подгрузил type library - UIAutomationClient интерфейсы IUIAutomation , IUIAutomationElement (UIAutomationClient_TLB)

```
function TForm1.getRect4(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var AUTOMATION : IUIAutomation;
  Root : IUIAutomationElement;
  rRect:UIAutomationClient_TLB.tagRECT;
  ElementOrientation:TOleEnum;
begin
    AUTOMATION := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
    AUTOMATION.GetRootElement(Root);
    AUTOMATION.ElementFromHandle(Pointer(AKeyboardWindow), Root);
    Root.Get_CurrentBoundingRectangle(rRect);
    Result :=  TRect(rRect);
end;

function TForm1.getRect5(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var AUTOMATION : IUIAutomation;
  Root : IUIAutomationElement;
  olRect: OleVariant;
  rRect:UIAutomationClient_TLB.tagRECT;
  ElementOrientation:TOleEnum;
  sWindowName: wideString;
begin
  AUTOMATION := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
  AUTOMATION.GetRootElement(Root);
  AUTOMATION.ElementFromHandle(Pointer(AKeyboardWindow), Root);
  Root.GetCurrentPropertyValue(BoundingRectangle, olRect);
  AUTOMATION.VariantToRect(olRect, rRect);

  Result :=  TRect(rRect);
end;
```

вызов клавиатуры

```
function ExpandEnvironmentVar(var Value: string): Boolean;
var
  R: Integer;
  Expanded: string;

procedure StrResetLength(var S: string);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    for I := 0 to Length(S) - 1 do
      if S[I + 1] = #0 then
      begin
        SetLength(S, I);
        Exit;
      end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(Expanded, 1);
  R := ExpandEnvironmentStrings(PChar(Value), PChar(Expanded), 0);
  SetLength(Expanded, R);
  Result := ExpandEnvironmentStrings(PChar(Value), PChar(Expanded), R) <> 0;
  if Result then
  begin
    StrResetLength(Expanded);
    Value := Expanded;
  end;
end;



procedure TForm1.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyHandle1: THandle;
begin
  MyHandle1 := FindWindow('IPTip_Main_Window', nil);
  if MyHandle1 <> 0 then
    PostMessage(MyHandle1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
end;



procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  btnClose.Click;
  S := '%CommonProgramW6432%\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe';
  ExpandEnvironmentVar(S);
  ShellExecute(0, PChar('open'), PChar(S), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Ничего не получилось(left = 0 top = 0 width = 0 height = 0)! Кто-нибудь что-то подобное делал, или знает что делать?

Comment: [Решение базируется на IFrameworkInputPaneHandler интерфейсе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226891/size-and-position-of-tabtip-exe-virtual-keyboard-on-windows-10)